# Why am I getting asyncio timeout running python in docker container, but not when running elsewhere

Tags: python-3.x, docker, timeout, python-asyncio

I have a python script that includes the following:

```
await asyncio.wait_for(subscriptionhandler(), 0.5)
```

This is code I've been using for weeks on an AWS box as part of some automated tests, without problem. I'm now trying to move my test set up to docker. When I run exactly the same code, the above line calls subscriptionhandler(), and in there I can see the correct behaviour, before subscriptionhandler() exits... at which point the above line throws an asyncio timeout exception.

Can anyone suggest why running in docker would cause this to happen? I had though it might be a networking issue (due to what happens in my handler) - but as I say above, all seems fine on that front - it's literally throwing the timeout exception for no reason.

docker-compose.yml:

```
  debugservice:
    image: cypress/included:10.11.0
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
    privileged: true
    container_name: cypress # Name for the container
    working_dir: /opt/testing
    ports: 
      - "9022:22"
      - "9200:9200"
      #     network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ${HOME}/.ssh/:/root/.ssh/
      - /home/myuser/dev/auto-tests/cypress/e2e:/opt/testing/cypress/e2e
      - /home/myuser/dev/auto-tests/cypress/fixtures:/opt/testing/cypress/fixtures
      - /home/myuser/dev/auto-tests/cypress/pages:/opt/testing/cypress/pages
      - /home/myuser/dev/auto-tests/cypress.config.ts:/opt/testing/cypress.config.ts
      - /home/myuser/dev/auto-tests/tsconfig.json:/opt/testing/tsconfig.json
      - /home/myuser/dev/auto-tests/python/scripts:/opt/testing/python/scripts
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/browsers:node16.16.0-chrome105-ff104-edge

ENV CI=1 \
  QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 \
  _X11_NO_MITSHM=1 \
  _MITSHM=0 \
  CYPRESS_CACHE_FOLDER=/root/.cache/Cypress \
  NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules

ARG CI_XBUILD

RUN echo "whoami: $(whoami)" \
  && npm config -g set user $(whoami) \
  && id \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
  && apt-get install -y python3-venv \
  && ls -la /root \
  && chmod 755 /root \
  && npm i -g yarn@latest \
  && node -p 'module.paths' \
  && echo  " node version:    $(node -v) \n" \
    "npm version:     $(npm -v) \n" \
    "yarn version:    $(yarn -v) \n" \
    "typescript version:  $(tsc -v) \n" \
    "debian version:  $(cat /etc/debian_version) \n" \
    "user:            $(whoami) \n" \
    "chrome:          $(google-chrome --version || true) \n" \
    "firefox:         $(firefox --version || true) \n"
WORKDIR /opt/testing/python
RUN pwd
COPY pycs .
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=pip_conf,dst=/root/.pip/pip.conf pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /opt/testing/cypress/support
COPY cypress/support .
WORKDIR /opt/testing
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
```

Comment: Please include your Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml file, the command that you're using to run the container(s), and other relevant information

Comment: Could it simply be that the 0.5s timeout is too small? What if you change it to 5s?

Comment: @fancidev I did try upping the timeout - no joy. The handler function comes back really quickly, but the wait_for just throws the error regardless...

Comment: If it's `subscriptionhandler()` that's exiting, what's happening inside of it?

Comment: So subscriptionhandler() contains an async for loop... and even though the object it was iterating over (generated by some in house code) only had one item inside (which I've since been told would always be the case(!!), it was processing that item, and then timing out, trying to do something else. changing the code to add an unconditional break inside the async loop solved the problem.

Now, why / how it was working without the break, outside of the docker container - no idea!

So it's solved now - it wasn't docker / asyncio at all, but something in code developed by someone else here!